# Read value from EventEmitter in same component

Tags: angular

It is possible to read the value of an `EventEmitter` object in the same component?

Imagine there is a child component with a variable called `fetchedArticle` declared as an `EventEmitter`.

```
@Output() fetchedArticle = new EventEmitter<Article>();
```

But before I switch the child component to the next component where I Need this output Event value, I want to Show some Details of the `$Event` value of the `EventEmitter` variable. And that should happen in the same component as the `fetchedArticle` `EventEmitter` is declared. 
I supposed to use something like

```
<h2>{{fetchedArticle.title}}</h2>
```

in the template of this component. But that wouldn`t work. 
Can anyone help me?

Comment: assign the value you pass to the event emitter in a variable and use it in the html template

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to the EventEmitter in your template using the async pipe like this:

```
<h2 *ngIf="(fetchedArticle | async) as article">{{ article.title }}</h2>
```

Comment: Hm...no that's not working. But thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Can you share the code where you are emitting a value? Do you get any errors?